# I have an issue using the join function in python, Kindly help me out

Tags: python

I want to display the path "C:\Test\file.txt", using the os.path.join function.

I assigned the path "C:\Test" to variable X and then used the os.listdir function to assign the files under the path of "C:\Test" to variable Y.

Finally I am trying to concatenate the two variables X and Y to display the complete path "C:\Test\file.txt" using the os.path.join function. But when I execute the code, I am displayed with the attached error. Kindly let me know where I am wrong.

I am using a Windows Machine and Python 3.8.2 Shell editor

This is my code:

```
import os
import os.path
x="C:\\Test"
y=os.listdir(x)
print(os.path.join(x,y))
```

[image]

Comment: What's not clear about the error? `y` is a **list** containing all files in that path. You can't concatenate a whole list to a string. You might want to loop on `y` like `for file in y:` and then concatenate each separate path like `print(os.path.join(x, file))`

Comment: As a side note, you should look into [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) for working with paths, rather than the `os.path` module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code:

```
import os
x = os.getcwd()
y = os.listdir(x)
y = [os.path.join(x, i) for i in y]
print(y)
```

Some more code snippets to play with `os.path`

```
import os
x = os.getcwd()
files_dirs_with_path = [os.path.abspath(x) for x in os.listdir()]
files_with_path = [os.path.abspath(x) for x in os.listdir() if os.path.isfile(os.path.abspath(x))]
```

Below code is kind of fun with `map` but not preferred for the realtime program

```
list(map(os.path.join, list(len(os.listdir(x))*[x]), os.listdir(x)))
```

Comment: Thanks ..Worked out perfectly. But can u clarify me on the part of using the for loop here.

Comment: That is the compact version of the multiline code.
`for x in os.listdir()` we're appending every parse into the list. But since clarity and readability should always be a priority in Python, it's better to write it as the multiline statements, if you've more to write.

Answer (score 0):

The join function takes two *strings* as arguments. What you are doing is giving it a string (x) and a list of strings (y).
What you probably want is:

```
result = [os.path.join(x,f) for f in y]
```

This way you join each path on it's own

Answer (score 0):

> os.listdir(x) returns the list of entries inside x. So the
>   datatype of variable y is list.

You have to choose one of the directories from list y.

You can do this by indexing y.

Comment: [`listdir(x)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) returns a list of **all** entries inside `x`, not just directories...